# png images are not transparent in HTML

Tags: html, png

I have those Images:

[image: First image]

[image: Second Image]

But when I add them to the web app it shows like this:

[image: Result]

```
  return(
        <div onClick={actionListner}>
            <img src={imgSrc} alt="none"></img>
            <h4>{charName}</h4>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Your image is not transparent. It has an opaque checkerboard background.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise and isn't a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not with transparent backgrounds, the checkerboard is the actual background.

You can see this by opening the link and dragging the image in your browser